# Storm UI improper values and Capillary tool

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

I am quiet new to Apache Storm and have been trying with trident topology for Kafka i.e. **TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout**. All works fine except the Storm UI. Even though I've not produced any data to my topic, the Storm UI keeps showing invalid emitted/transferred values. Meaning the count keeps on increasing even when there is no data in the topic. I've tried deleting the data/logs stored in zookeeper, storm, kafka and recreate kafka topics and also have set

```
topology.stats.sample.rate: 1.0
```

but still the problem persists.

And also I came across a tool called [Capillary](https://github.com/keenlabs/capillary) to monitor storm cluster.
I am using the below properties

```
capillary.zookeepers="192.168.125.20:2181"
capillary.kafka.zkroot="192.168.125.20:/home/storm/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.0"
capillary.storm.zkroot="192.168.125.20:/home/storm/apache-storm-0.9.3"
```

I am using Kafka's embedded zookeeper here.
Even this is not working getting the below exception.

```
! @6mbg4bp7l - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@24adb083; line: 1, column: 9]]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@24adb083; line: 1, column: 9]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1524) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:557) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:475) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:495) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1178) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
```

Any help on either would be great. Thanks in advance.

Configuration and source code snippet:

```
 final Config config = new Config();
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TRIDENT_BATCH_EMIT_INTERVAL_MILLIS, 3000);
    config.setNumWorkers(2);
    config.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "192.168.125.20");
    config.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, 6627);
    config.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
    config.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, Arrays.asList("192.168.125.20"));
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_ACKER_EXECUTORS, 1);
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 10);
    config.put(Config.DRPC_SERVERS, Arrays.asList("192.168.125.20"));
    config.put(Config.DRPC_PORT, 3772);

final BrokerHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts("192.168.125.20");
final TridentKafkaConfig kafkaConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(zkHosts, "Test_Topic", "");
kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
kafkaConfig.bufferSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
kafkaConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
kafkaConfig.forceFromStart = false;

final TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new TransactionalTridentKafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
final TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
topology.newStream("spout", kafkaSpout)
       .each(new Fields("str"), new TestFunction(), new Fields("test"))
       .each(new Fields("str"), new PrintFilter());
```

Topology Summary Image : 
[image: Topology Stats]

Comment: Haven't use capillary, but it looks like something wrong with the config file.looking at their source code how does your conf/route file looks?

Comment: @user2720864 Thanks for your reply. I've updated my conf settings in my question.

Comment: I believe this is something wromng with Capillary. might worth looking at https://github.com/keenlabs/capillary/issues/5

Comment: @user2720864 Thanks again for your reply. Yes I did look at it. But I was hoping there could be some other solution from Storm end to view correct values in the Storm UI.

Comment: why not use the default storm ui to check if it works, at least that will confirm the code is fine and you can then focus on the capillary part

Comment: @user2720864 that is right. I did test it with the default storm ui. I tested with normal kafka spout with storm. The values showed up fine when I set **topology.stats.sample.rate: 1.0** Trident also works fine as expected. But as I mentioned the problem is with emitted/transferred showing up improper values in storm ui. I tried capillary just to monitor the storm and kafka topic since the storm ui was showing improper counts.

Comment: You may be seeing processed tuples on the control streams.  These will continue even if your main spout isn't producing new tuples.  You should be able to see a breakdown of what stream the tuples are coming from in the bolt's UI page.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell Thanks for your reply. Apparently my bolt has not started processing since the spout has no data to read from the kafka topic. But still I could see the emitted/transferred being increased all the time in the topology summary page as well as in spout0 component summary page. I don't understand how/why this is happening. I could not see anything in the logs too. I've just embedded the image to my original question which shows the stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you possibly seeing the what I'd call the [UI metric artifacts of Trident](http://qnalist.com/questions/5172389/trident-kafka-spout-ack-count-increasing-even-though-no-messages-are-processed)?  These tuples also show up in counters of the Storm UI:

> Trident executes a batch every 500ms (by default). A batch involves a bunch
>   of coordination messages going out to all the bolts to coordinate the batch
>   (even if the batch is empty). So that's what you're seeing.
>
> (source: [Trident Kafka Spout - Ack Count Increasing Even Though No Messages Are Processed](http://qnalist.com/questions/5172389/trident-kafka-spout-ack-count-increasing-even-though-no-messages-are-processed))

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Yes probably that is what I am seeing in the UI. The co-ordination messages shouldn't have been shown as emitted/processed values which leads to confusion   in knowing the actual values.
Is there a way to get the actual number of messages emitted/processed leaving out the co-ordination message counts as asked in the link you mentioned?

Comment: @DMA Did you find any way to get around this?

Comment: @miguno Links seems to be expired. Do you have alternate links?

Comment: @Sach Nothing till now.